# How to estimate ngram probability?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, n-gram

I want to build a language model where I want to estimate the ngram probabilities. So, my question is: What are the best corpora and tools that we could use to estimate the ngram probabilities?.

thanks

Comment: You could try berkeleylm: https://code.google.com/p/berkeleylm/. Some pre-built models are available at http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/berkeleylm_binaries/ for the Google Web 1T corpus.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this? : You can use it without calculating it again from scratch : 
http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

For easier download see this: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-ngram-downloader/

Answer (score 0):

**In 2023** the largest dataset for ngram frequencies is the [Google Books Ngram Dataset v3](https://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv3.html).

For searching the dataset online there is the [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) and [NGRAMS](https://ngrams.dev). The latter provides a REST API where you can fetch the raw data.